# Abstract class with class typed properties

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm deserializing some JSON responses and putting them into one of two primary classes depending on if a single object is returned or if a list of objects is returned. I'm currently using

```
public class MultiResponse
{
    public List<DeserializedResult> Result { get; set; }
}

public class SingleResponse
{
    public DeserializedResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class DeserializedResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

to contain the response(s). However I know it's not the best way, especially since I'm having to use a dynamic return in the calling class to deal with the two types of responses possible. I think an abstract class (or interface?) is a better way to do this, but I don't know how to implement it. Am I on the right track & if so, how do I construct the abstract class and do the inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a design based on multi responses - i.e. holding / returning a list even if when there is only one object. It eliminates the design "hint" that there is a special case somehow. And The resulting code will be more consistent and robust.

The focus should be on the object itself - what you do with it after re-hydration. Not on the trivial happenstance that I have one object or more than one. That distinction is no different that "4 objects or not 4 objects."

Abstracting the container to a single class necessarily makes working with the objects the focus, the emphasis of your design.

**edit**

Think of it this way. Single or multiple deserialized objects is a consequence of how many objects there were to deserialize. It is an implementation detail not germane to the (deserialized) objects actual use. **Encapsulate implementation details**, that is, hide them from the client code. Give clients classes and methods that express functionality in "business domain" terms.

**end edit**

---

**Edit**

> ... I'm having to use a dynamic return in the calling class to deal with the two types of responses possible.  I think an abstract class (or interface?) is a better way to do this, but I don't know how to implement it.

Main points:

- `ClientApi` transforms the deserialized object to the desired class.

  - Two API's!

    - constructors called by the de-hydrating object
    - Hide the default constructor to ensure valid object instantiation
    - `GetDeHydratedJsonThingy` called by the "using" client.
- Deserializer and "using" client are decoupled thanks to the `ClientApi` class.

  - De-hydration works with `DeserializedResults` objects
  - "Using" client only cares about `MultipleResponse` objects
- "using" client deals with only one return type.

P.S. After I wrote this I realized only one "Response" class is needed, now that `ClientApi` class encapsulates the object instantiations. Commented out code is original.

P.P.S.  My method and parameter names are really lousy. Use names that have meaning in the problem domain. i.e. user's terminology.

.

```
public class ClientApi {
    protected MultiResponse MoreThanOne { get; set; }
    // protected SingleResponse OnlyOne    { get; set; }

    protected ClientApi ( );

    public ClientApi (List<DeserializedResult> theList) {
        if (theList == null) throw ArgumentNullException("error message here");

        // add overloaded constructors to MultiResponse class.
        MoreThanOne = new MultiResponse (theList);
       // OnlyOne = null;
    }

    public ClientApi (DeserializedResult onlyOne)
        if (onlyOne == null) throw ArgumentNullException("error message here");

        MoreThanOne = new MultiResponse(onlyOne);
       // OnlyOne = onlyOne;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Always returns an object. The list may be empty, 
    /// but never null
    ///</summary>
    public MultiResponse GetDeHydratedJsonThingy() {
        MultiResponse HereYaGo = new MultiResponse();
      //  if (MoreThanOne !=null) HereYaGo.AddRange(MoreThanOne);
      //  if (OnlyOne != null) HereYaGo.Add(OnlyOne);

        HereYaGo.AddRange(MoreThanOne.Result);
        return HereYaGo;
    }
}
```

**end Edit**

Comment: I need to differentiate for the deserialization. I get errors if I try to deserialize a list vs a single object. This is the simplest, least overhead way I can think of.

Comment: Ok, YOU need to, but why should the client code? Do what you have to, but transmogrify it so clients deal with only one thing. Don't expose your implementation problems to clients. Give them a clean, consistant API to work with.

Comment: "... this is the simplest, least overhead way..." 1 Class is simpler than 2. One return type is simpler than 2. Think about what the client is forced to do. I see the potential for at least some special handling code. You are making the API more complex, that's what matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following with a generic base abstract class

```
public abstract class Response<T> {
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

The concrete implementations would inherit from the common base response.

```
public class Response : Response<object> {
    public object Result { get; set; }
}

public class MultiResponse : Response<List<DeserializedResult>> {
    public List<DeserializedResult> Result { get; set; }
}

public class SingleResponse : Response<DeserializedResult> {
    public DeserializedResult Result { get; set; }
}
```